# In jquery can I chain .filter twice?

Tags: jquery

Why does this work, but the second example does not?

First one works.

```
function someFunk() {
   $('.listOne li').filter(':odd').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
   $('.listOne li').filter(':even').css('background-color', '#F0F0F0');
};
```

Second one does not work.

```
function someFunk() {
   $('.listOne li').filter(':odd').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF').filter(':even').css('background-color', '#F0F0F0');
};
```

Can I not chain .filter() in jquery?

Comment: You can chain, however, filtering the odd ones to only even ones doesn't make sense. That's like saying give me all apples out of the fruit basket, and then filter those apples to only apples that are oranges.

Comment: So I am just doing this all wrong?

Comment: I miss you add a end()

Comment: You just needed to revert the collection back to the collection before the initial filter, which the answer below demonstrates. The equation becomes: Give me all apples out of the fruit basket, now, put them back and give me all oranges out of the fruit basket.

Comment: function someFunk() {
   $('.listOne li').filter(':odd').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF').end().filter(':even').css('background-color', '#F0F0F0');
};

Comment: So I have to just use .end(). I didn't see that in the jquery .filter() docs. I must have missed that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to return to the previous stack after DOM navigation methods.:

```
$('.listOne li').filter(':odd').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF')
.end().filter(':even').css('background-color', '#F0F0F0');
```